# When new content is added, it goes to the bottom of the website

Tags: html, css

Every time i add new content to my website, it goes like 40 lines down from the other content. I think its because I re-positioned a lot of my content. But who do I close that "gap" on my website so it flows back under the other content.

code

```
#start{
                position: relative;
                bottom:300px;
                left:700px;
                font-size: 35px;
                border-style: none;
                border-radius: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background-color: orange;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;



            }
            #instruction-button{
                position: relative;
                bottom:240px;
                left:300px;
                font-size: 35px;
                border-style: none;
                border-radius: 20px;
                background-color: orange;
                font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
            }
```

Comment: Please attach your codes :)

Comment: CODES PLEASE!!!Here is not a place to write stories so when you ask programming questions Make sure you have written your code.

Comment: I added it above, but every time i added a box, i would float it left but i want one under it, so i would have to "position: relative" it. So because of that, it left a lot of empty spaces causing the program to think i have something there.

Comment: @Jon2713 You still didn't add your html But as I see your css I guess `bottom:300px;'` is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a div is too big and it is appended after the div? Try shrinking the div size or appending the object inside the div. Otherwise I don't know. If you paste the code that is giving you a problem it may be easier to find the issue.

Comment: I added it above, but every time i added a box, i would float it left but i want one under it, so i would have to "position: relative" it. So because of that, it left a lot of empty spaces causing the program to think i have something there.